# update-initramfs and linux-firmware while installing and updating softwares

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, update-manager

I'm using Kubuntu 19.04 and I've updated the KDE Desktop to version 5.16.2
I keep getting the following errors while performing a software update or installation through KDE Discover(Software center) and Konsole(Terminal).
Some Background info:I increased the size of my root(/) partition earlier.

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.178.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-20-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries 
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs 
    integration and avoid this warning.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda8
I: (UUID=dc2cd463-e46e-4cbd-b14f-ed811bf6526c)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-20-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
```

output of df -h,df -i:

```
ak@ak-pc:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M   12M  374M   3% /run
/dev/sda6       8.6G  5.6G  2.5G  70% /
tmpfs           1.9G  6.2M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       23M   23M     0 100% /snap/snapd/3646
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1049
/dev/loop3       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop4       36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop2      266M  266M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/29
/dev/loop5       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/1013
/dev/sda5       180M  156M   12M  94% /boot
/dev/sda7        11G  3.9G  6.4G  38% /home
tmpfs           385M   12K  385M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3       366G  331G   36G  91% /media/ak/AC4A56F84A56BEB0
ak@ak-pc:~$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             483633    581   483052    1% /dev
tmpfs            492446    920   491526    1% /run
/dev/sda6        567840 194674   373166   35% /
tmpfs            492446     11   492435    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            492446      5   492441    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            492446     18   492428    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          627    627        0  100% /snap/snapd/3646
/dev/loop1        10031  10031        0  100% /snap/core18/1049
/dev/loop3        12823  12823        0  100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop4        25385  25385        0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop2        33964  33964        0  100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/29
/dev/loop5         9877   9877        0  100% /snap/core18/1013
/dev/sda5         48768    314    48454    1% /boot
/dev/sda7        718080   8798   709282    2% /home
tmpfs            492446     34   492412    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3      37240056  16439 37223617    1% /media/ak/AC4A56F84A56BEB0
```

Comment: `df -h;df -i`  please add the output to your question.

Comment: @nobody I've added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your `/boot` partition is full. That is most probably due to many linux kernels being installed. The process to fix this is as follows:

- open a terminal and become `root` or use `sudo`
- find list of installed kernels `dpkg -l | egrep 'linux.*(image|header)'` and save it someplace safe to refer to it.
- Find your current kernel version `uname -r` and save it for reference
- remove at least one combination of `image` and `header` package to free space `apt-get autoremove --purge linux-headers-4.15.0-52 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic`
- take care to not remove your current version and the latest one (look at the numbers and judge)
- Take care not to remove all kernels
- rebuild all initrds `update-initrd -u -k all`
- clean unneeded packages `apt-get autoremove --purge`

That should fix your issue

Comment: Thanks I thought there is only one kernel in Linux and Do I need multiple kernels?

Comment: There is one running kernel but you can have multiple kernels (e.g. for different purposes, different versions and so on). It is completely normal to have more than one installed.

Comment: After typing update-initrd -u -k all in the terminal it says command not found

Comment: You need to do it as root (prefix with sudo)

Comment: I tried it but it did not work https://imgur.com/ayS874q

Comment: @zeridon
`sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: @nobody Thank you but I'm still getting this https://imgur.com/ARgfWj6

Comment: if the /boot or /-partition is not encryted  you can purge  cryptsetup-initramfs. By the way this is only a warning. If your system boots well you can ignore it.

Comment: @nobody Thank you very much :),I thought i need to reinstall the kubuntu again to fix this issue.